# Terraform bastion host module for Azure

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to build a terraform module to provision Azure Landing Zone.

Currently, I have 3 working modules:

Resource_Groups
Storage_Accounts
Virtual_Networks

The new module is Bastion_Host
main.tf Code:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "bastion_pubip" {
  name                = "${var.bastionhost_name}PIP-01"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegroup_name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  tags                = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_bastion_host" "bastion" {
  name                = var.bastionhost_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegroup_name
  tags                = var.tags

  ip_configuration {
    name                 = "bastion_config"
    subnet_id = var.subnet_id
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.bastion_pubip.id
  }
}
```

variables.tf code:

```
variable "resourcegroup_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  default     = "Networking-CC-RG"
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "The region for the deployment"
  default     = "canadacentral"
}

variable "tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Tags used for the deployment"
  default = {
    "Environment"   = "Development"
    "Owner"         = "OwnerEmail"
    "CreatedBy"     = "JNuaman@outlook.com"

  }
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "the name of the vnet"
  default     = "VNET-Hub-CC-Prod-01"
}

variable "subnet_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "the name of the vnet"
  default     = "AzureBastionSubnet"
}

variable "bastionhost_name" {
  type = string
  description = "the name of th bastion host"
  default = "VNET-Hub-CC-Prod-01-BH-01"
}
```

Root module:

```
module "Azure_Module_RG" {
  source = "./Modules/Resource_Groups"
}

module "Azure_Module_SA" {
  source = "./Modules/Storage_Accounts"
  depends_on = [ module.Azure_Module_RG ]
}

module "Azure_Module_VNET" {
  source = "./Modules/Virtual_Networks"
}

module "Azure_Module_BH" {
  source = "./modules/Bastion_Host"
  depends_on = [ module.Azure_Module_VNET ]
}
```

Error code:

> Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: parsing "AzureBastionSubnet": parsing Azure ID: parse "AzureBastionSubnet": invalid URI for request
│
│   with module.Azure_Module_BH.azurerm_bastion_host.bastion,
│   on modules\Bastion_Host\main.tf line 19, in resource "azurerm_bastion_host" "bastion":
│   19:     subnet_id = var.subnet_id

Any idea how to solve my mess?

Thanks

I tried playing with Subnet_id in many ways but it didn't work.